Is there any way to apply rotations and other transformations efficiently to a part in model in APS Viewer?
I am currently working on a project which involves a model of an actuator and valve. I am trying to animate a multi body mechanical system (Scotch-Yoke actuator).
I am able to get simple translation but facing issues in applying rotation to parts. Till now I have been using Three.js functions to modify and add motion to our model. But unable to get the required rotation of valve disk. The axis of rotation is not applying as expected, it has some offset from desired position.
I tried to apply rotation to valve disk using three.js. I am trying to rotate the disk around the axis which passes through 2 Points.
But when seen in the viewer, the axis of rotation does not pass through given points. Instead, it looks to be passing through origin and has some direction.

I would suggest having a look at this AU class that also talks about transformations and animations in the Viewer using a multi part robot:
https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Advanced-Techniques-Using-Forge-Viewer-2018
It also includes links to samples.

